# Deserialize Apache Solr complex object List

Tags: serialization, solr, deserialization

i'm a kind of newbie using Apache Solr, and i'm indexing a document witch has list of complex objectslike this:

```
{
    PropA: AnyValue,
    PropB: [{p1:'v1', p2:'v2'}, {p1:'v3', p2:'v4'}],
    PropC: [{p1:'v1', p2:'v2'}, {p1:'v3', p2:'v4'}]
}
```

When i send it to solr it will get tha same data but on a different format:

```
{
    PropA: AnyValue,
    PropB.p1: ['v1','v3']
    PropB.p2: ['v2','v4']
    PropC.p1: ['v1','v3']
    PropC.p2: ['v2','v4']
}
```

This format is causing me problems on deserializing, is it possible or what can i do to to get Solr to return the object on the original format?

Do i have to specify something special at the schema level to support Subdocuments? i'm kinda lost on this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To get well formatted document from SOLR you can use [carrot](http://project.carrot2.org/download-solr-compat.html) framework.
It easy to implement and you can generate XML or JSON format as par your custom requirement using XSLT.